# Is this thinking correct on how 'self' identifies between instance and static members?

Tags: python, oop

> I am learning OOP, so my question on the two statements below probably seems very basic to many, but I just want to check in case I am using Python/OO lingo in the wrong way:
>
>  - You must explicitly define 'self' as the first parameter in every class method.
>
>  - Python's explicit requirement of self as the first parameter of methods defined in classes, makes it so that it's clear to people what the difference between instance and static methods are.
>
>     If the statements are correct concerning the 'self' keyword, is it correct of me to infer that, either as a parameter in method definitions or as a prefix to variables; the presence of the word 'self' commonly indicates that a method or variable is static, whereas the absence of the word 'self' usually indicates that the method or variable is an instance method or variable?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the first parameter is not syntactically important. It's `self` for normal methods by convention, but that's not enforced.

What is syntactically important is how the method is constructed. A method is a normal method and will receive the instance it's called on as its first argument unless converted into a class method or static method by the [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) or [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) built in functions.

A class method receives the class as its first argument, which by convention is named `cls`. Although because class methods are less common than normal methods, I've seen more deviations from that convention than I have for normal methods. `klass` is not totally uncommon, and sometimes people are careless and use `self` out of habit.

A static method does not receive any automatic arguments.

```
class ExampleClass(object):

    def sample_instance_method(self):
        # this is a normal instance method
        pass

    @classmethod
    def sample_class_method(cls):
        # this is a class method, and will not receive the individual instance if called on one
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def sample_static_method():
        # this is a static method, and will not receive either the instance or the class when called
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

No, its the other way round.

But I can see why the doubt, these statements are confusing: you put `self` as first argument in instance methods, and you don't put it in static methods.

Note that although there is no need in naming that first parameter `self`, it is better to follow that convention as it is clearer to the reader.

Also, don't name `self`the first parameter in a static method, it is possible, yes, but you will for sure confuse the reader.